# Making a piece of code that loops 5 times and stores the information that it generates each individual time into separate variables

Tags: java

I'm an absolute beginner at coding in and I'm trying to make some code that runs 5 times, and for each time it runs, places what it generates into 5 different variables for me to compare later, so far I have this, it's code that when run tosses a coin 1000 times and keeps track of the amount of heads and tails it produces, is there any way that I can have it loop 5 times, and store the count in different variables each time, i.e first time it loops it will store the first amount of heads into countH and the second into one called countH2 or would I have to try and make it a different way? Any help is appreciated.

Question now solved, thanks

Comment: Please try to focus on using "correct" indentation. It makes your code easier to read. I've fixed it for you this time.

Comment: "*first time it loops it will store the first amount of heads into countH and the second into one called countH2*" This is not possible in a language like Java. Variable names are fixed at compile-time, they cannot be based on dynamic values, like the content of another variable (like some integer counter). Some interpreted languages can do this kind of thing. What you are looking for in your case is an array or List.

Comment: Will do sorry about that, this is my first post so I'm still getting use to how everything works here.

Comment: Oracle Arrays tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html there are probably better ones out there, but if you want it straight from the horse's mouth, you can't go wrong with that

Comment: Thank you so much, will take a look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public class Toss {
public final int HEADS = 0;
static int countH = 0;
static int countT = 0;
static int amount = 0;
           
private static int side;

public static void flip() {
    side = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
}

public String toString() {
    String sideName;
    if (amount == 1000){
        amount = 0;
        countH = 0;
        countT = 0;
    }
    if (side == HEADS) {
        sideName = "Heads";
        countH++;
        amount++;
    } else {
        sideName = "Tails";
        countT++;
        amount++;
    }
    
    return sideName;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] x = new int[5][2];
    
    int cnt = 0;
    do {
        do {
            flip();
            new Toss().toString();
        } while (amount != 1000);
        x[cnt][0] = countH;
        x[cnt][1] = countT;
        cnt++;
    } while (cnt < 5);
    
    cnt = 0;
    
    do {  
    System.out.println(cnt);
    System.out.println("Number of Tails: " + x[cnt][0]);
    System.out.println("Number of Heads: " + x[cnt][1]);
    cnt++;
    
    }while (cnt < 5);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of integers in order to hold the value of countH every time you want your while loop to run.

This would allow you to contain the output together as a group of similar values.

Here is a link that explains how arrays work:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-in-java/

good luck with your program